# Troubleshoot overkilled webserver when scanned with tool

Tags: php, apache, nginx

I have decent webserver, it uses Plesk and within Plesk I have configured to use Apache and nginx as a proxy.

The problem I had was that while I was running a scanner to audit my website, I was getting an error from nginx that apache had Timeout. Which I fixed by increasing the proxy_read_timeout flag on nginx configuration.

Now, when I run the audit again the server becomes really slow, and if I leave it running for a while I get "Server is temporarily unavailable"

The VPS is a 4core, with 8gb of ram and 160ssd, not high number of users, so I can't understand why this is happening, I checked logs and there is no error message.

I believe this must be a miss-configuration, but what can I check to troubleshoot a server that cannot handle multiple requests?

The tool I use for scan seopowersuite which is simply gathering html and parsing it to analyze.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the scanner hits any file with high CPU or RAM usage? 
Or with long running loops?

Comment: It could be but then php logs should tell me that. I am basically wondering on which logs I have to check.
htop shows high cpu for mysql

Comment: Not really an answer